# Why making temporary table is faster than multiple WHERE conditions?

Tags: performance, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I have a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Sessions (
  SessionId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ExternalId int(11) NOT NULL,
  Active bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

ALTER TABLE Sessions
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (SessionId),
  ADD KEY ExternalId (ExternalId),
  ADD KEY Active (Active);
```

This table contains over 40 millions row, with only 2k row set as active, and only like 3 lines per ExternalId.

I want to get all active sessions for a precise `ExternalId`. So, I basically made:

```
SELECT * FROM Sessions WHERE Active = 1 AND ExternalId = myId;
```

But, it takes lot of time (over 3 seconds). After some investigation, I found that this one is faster:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Sessions WHERE Active = 1) x WHERE x.ExternalId = myId;
```

With this, it take around 0.005 seconds.

I would to know why making a temporary table is faster than a basic where check with 2 params?

Comment: Test `CREATE INDEX idx ON Sessions (ExternalId, Active)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first query, mariadb needs to decide whether to use index on Active or on ExternaId.
Since Active is a boolean field, it probably assumes that half the rows (20 millions) will satisfy the condition, and it will use the index on ExternalId thinking it can be more efficient.

In the second one, you force it to first select the Active sessions, using the Active index. If the active sessions are just a tiny fraction of the table, this results in a few rows, which have then to be scanned to find the ones where ExternalId corresponds to the one you are selecting.

Using EXPLAIN on both queries should give you info on what index maridab is using.

Comment: On first query, mariadb doesn't use both index? How can I say the active field is more efficient that the ExternalId's one? I just edited my question to say that the active field can filter around 99% of field

Comment: @Elikill58 In general, a dbms can read any single table using either a scan or one (and only one) of the indexes on that table. The query optimizer must decide what option (table scan, index on SessionId, index on Active, index on ExternalId) is better to use in a select where table Session is present. To use both Active and ExternalID you have to add an index on both columns, as Akina suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much faster and simpler to use a composite index:

```
INDEX(Active, ExternalId)
```

The order of those two columns does not matter.  When adding that, drop the current `INDEX(Active)` as unnecessary.

A nitpick about terminology:  `FROM ( SELECT ... )` is a "derived table".  A temporary table is `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...` or an implicitly created temp table.  The Optimizer *may or may not* use an implicit temp table to implement a derived table.

In your original query, what is "myid"?  Is it a number?  An argument to a stored routine?  A string?  If it is a simple literal number, I would expect the optimizer to use `INDEX(ExternalId)`, find 3 rows, then decide which one(s) are `Active`.  This *should* have been plenty fast.  So...  I smells like the statistics are messed up.  Run `ANALYZE TABLE Sessions;`.  (This kind of problem is very rare.)